# Create li with changing background images and a link

Tags: html, css

I created a list and each `li` element has a background image which changes when hovering over the `li`. Additionally the `li` should contain a link to another webpage.

I assume its bad html to write `<a href="..."><li></li></a>` - We should avoid that, right?

But how can I create a link inside the `li` element which links to another page and additionally the CSS which changes the background picture is still active?

HTML:

```
<li class="list_skybox"><a href="skybox.html"></a></li>
```

CSS:

```
.list_skybox {
  background: url('../img/skybox_unactive.png') no-repeat;

}

.list_skybox:hover {
  background: url('../img/skybox.png') no-repeat;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: But the background still DOES change! http://jsfiddle.net/T8XzY/

Comment: What's wrong with what you've got? Your own solution looks viable. Perhaps you could set up and example jsfiddle for us to evaluate.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/geQ2C/

Comment: Is it that you want the entire image to be clickable?

Comment: Perhaps http://jsfiddle.net/blaird/T8XzY/1/ ?

Comment: Explain why you are trying to style the `li` items, while it's really the `a` elements you want to work on.